# Placing objects on canvas

Tags: d3.js

I want to place circles and rectangles on a canvas, in such a way that circles form the inner layout and rectangles connected to circles form an outer layout.

I place all circles in circular fashion and that works as expected using normal mathematics(rsinQ,rcosQ).

Now the real problem arises when I need to place rectangles connected to circles, in the external path of circles. The thing is I am not sure how many rectangles will be connected to a circle (typically there can be 0 to 3 Rectangles connected to 1 circle). Now, I'm faced with the dilemma on placing them on canvas.

Again reminding, no of circles and rectangles is not known up till runtime.

Comment: Could you subdivide the external path and place a square at the midpoint of each segment? For example, you are drawing 3 squares on a 120deg arc, so draw a rectangle every 40deg.

Comment: Hi david , thanks for your suggestion I did the same thing, now I am stuck with force.on("tick" , here is my code to draw now this is getting called endlessly so my logic gets break, can i stop this force.on("tick" to be executed just once?